# BeautifulSoup - easy way to to obtain HTML-free contents

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, html-content-extraction

I'm using this code to find all interesting  links in a page:

```
soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('^notizia.php\?idn=\d+'))
```

And it does its job pretty well. Unfortunately inside that **a** tag there are a lot of nested tags, like **font**, **b** and different things... I'd like to get just the text content, without any other html tag.

Example of link:

```
<A HREF="notizia.php?idn=1134" OnMouseOver="verde();" OnMouseOut="blu();"><FONT CLASS="v12"><B>03-11-2009:&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color=green>CCS Ingegneria Elettronica-Sportello studenti ed orientamento</B></FONT></A>
```

Of course it's ugly (and the markup is not always the same!) and I'd like to get:

```
03-11-2009:  CCS Ingegneria Elettronica-Sportello studenti ed orientamento
```

In the documentation it says to use `text=True` in findAll method, but it will ignore my regex. Why? How can I solve that?

Comment: PyQuery sounds like a really cool alternative: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've used this:

```
def textOf(soup):
    return u''.join(soup.findAll(text=True))
```

So...

```
texts = [textOf(n) for n in soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('^notizia.php\?idn=\d+'))]
```

Comment: I think you need a loop - you can't call `findAll` on a result set, only on a single result.

Answer (score 2):

Interested in a pyparsing take on the problem?

```
from pyparsing import makeHTMLTags, SkipTo, anyOpenTag, anyCloseTag, ParseException

htmlsrc = """<A HREF="notizia.php?idn=1134" OnMouseOver="verde();" OnMouseOut="blu();"><FONT CLASS="v12"><B>03-11-2009:&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color=green>CCS Ingegneria Elettronica-Sportello studenti ed orientamento</B></FONT></A>"""

# create pattern to find interesting <A> tags
aStart,aEnd = makeHTMLTags("A")
def matchInterestingHrefsOnly(t):
    if not t.href.startswith("notizia.php?"):
        raise ParseException("not interested...")
aStart.setParseAction(matchInterestingHrefsOnly)
patt = aStart + SkipTo(aEnd)("body") + aEnd

# create pattern to strip HTML tags, and convert HTML entities
stripper = anyOpenTag.suppress() | anyCloseTag.suppress()
def stripTags(s):
    s = stripper.transformString(s)
    s = s.replace("&nbsp;"," ")
    return s


for match in patt.searchString(htmlsrc):
    print stripTags(match.body)
```

Prints:

```
03-11-2009:  CCS Ingegneria Elettronica-Sportello studenti ed orientamento
```

This is actually pretty impervious to HTML vagaries, as it factors in presence/absence of attributes, upper/lower case, and so on.