# How to scrape only visible webpage text with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, text, beautifulsoup, html-content-extraction

Basically, I want to use `BeautifulSoup` to grab strictly the *visible text* on a webpage. For instance, [this webpage](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/12/21/us/21storm.html) is my test case. And I mainly want to just get the body text (article) and maybe even a few tab names here and there. I have tried the suggestion in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752662/beautifulsoup-easy-way-to-to-obtain-html-free-contents) that returns lots of `<script>` tags and html comments which I don't want. I can't figure out the arguments I need for the function [`findAll()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#arg-limit) in order to just get the visible texts on a webpage.

So, how should I find all visible text excluding scripts, comments, css etc.?

Comment: There is an update for newer `BeautifulSoup`  Versions 4.9.+ https://stackoverflow.com/a/73701993/14460824

Answer (score 304, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment
import urllib.request


def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']:
        return False
    if isinstance(element, Comment):
        return False
    return True


def text_from_html(body):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)  
    return u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)

html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.nytimes.com/2009/12/21/us/21storm.html').read()
print(text_from_html(html))
```

Comment: @jbochi I've replaced line 3 of visible() with re.match('.*<!--.*-->.*', string, re.DOTALL). Yours seems to only work if the *entire* contents of text is a comment, but if there's an initial space or new line then 'invisible' html will be returned. My solution is overly aggressive in that it will mark the entire element as invisible, but for my purposes that's just fine.

Comment: +1 for `soup.findAll(text=True)` never knew about that feature

Comment: For recent BS4 (at least) you could identify comments with `isinstance(element, Comment)` instead of matching with a regex.

Comment: This did not work for me because I had a nested div tag in a script tag, which does not render on many browsers.

Comment: I believe line 2 should be ````soup = BeautifulSoup(html)````

Comment: @jbochi you just saved my day.. truly wonderful script. I have modified slightly ur script and put it in try: except: to avoid some ` File "<interactive input>", line 3, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 18: ordinal not in range(128) ` errors. also, had my own function to study the parent of those texts.. to print just the text i need... `def make_print_original(vis_text):
    for myl in vis_text:
        print 'Parent: ', myl.parent.name
        print 'Text:   ', str(myl)
        print '\n\n========='`

Comment: @Kshitij It's the `re` (regular expressions aka regex) module. I'd link you but I'm on mobile, sorry

Comment: In the visible function, the elif for finding comments didn't seem to work. i had to update it to `elif isinstance(element,bs4.element.Comment):`. I also added 'meta' to the list of parents.

Comment: The above filter has a lot of \n in the result, add the following code to eliminate white spaces and new lines:  `elif re.match(r"[\s\r\n]+",str(element)):
            return False`

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is a [document] tag? I couldn't find it by googling.

Comment: Could you please explain text_from_html line by line. Especially, what do the last 3 lines do? Thank you

Comment: @夜一林风, your codes worked for me. so the whole piece is: import re
def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']: return False      if isinstance(element, Comment):return False
    elif re.match(r"[\s\r\n]+",str(element)): return False
    return True                                                                                                                    def text_from_html(body):
    [SAME WITH original Code]

Answer (score 40):

The approved answer from @jbochi does not work for me.  The str() function call raises an exception because it cannot encode the non-ascii characters in the BeautifulSoup element.  Here is a more succinct way to filter the example web page to visible text.

```
html = open('21storm.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
[s.extract() for s in soup(['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title'])]
visible_text = soup.getText()
```

Comment: If `str(element)` fails with encoding problems, you should try `unicode(element)` instead if you are using Python 2.

Answer (score 37):

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.yahoo.com"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

print(text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: The previous answers did not work for me, but this did :)

Comment: If I try this on the url imfuna.com it only returns 6 words (Imfuna Property Inventory and Inspection Apps) despite the fact there is much more text/words on the page... any ideas why this answer doesn't work for that url? @bumpkin

Comment: is there a way to replace `<br>` tags with `\n` newline characters?

Answer (score 11):

I completely respect using Beautiful Soup to get rendered content, but it may not be the ideal package for acquiring the rendered content on a page.

I had a similar problem to get rendered content, or the visible content in a typical browser.  In particular I had many perhaps atypical cases to work with such a simple example below.  In this case the non displayable tag is nested in a style tag, and is not visible in many browsers that I have checked.  Other variations exist such as defining a class tag setting display to none.  Then using this class for the div.

```
<html>
  <title>  Title here</title>

  <body>

    lots of text here <p> <br>
    <h1> even headings </h1>

    <style type="text/css"> 
        <div > this will not be visible </div> 
    </style>


  </body>

</html>
```

One solution posted above is:

```
html = Utilities.ReadFile('simple.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
visible_texts = filter(visible, texts)
print(visible_texts)


[u'\n', u'\n', u'\n\n        lots of text here ', u' ', u'\n', u' even headings ', u'\n', u' this will not be visible ', u'\n', u'\n']
```

This solution certainly has applications in many cases and does the job quite well generally but in the html posted above it retains the text that is not rendered.  After searching SO a couple solutions came up here [BeautifulSoup get_text does not strip all tags and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524387/beautifulsoup-get-text-does-not-strip-all-tags-and-javascript/)  and here [Rendered HTML to plain text using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337528/rendered-html-to-plain-text-using-python)

I tried both these solutions: html2text and nltk.clean_html and was surprised by the timing results so thought they warranted an answer for posterity.  Of course, the speeds highly depend on the contents of the data...

One answer here from @Helge was about using nltk of all things.

```
import nltk

%timeit nltk.clean_html(html)
was returning 153 us per loop
```

It worked really well to return a string with rendered html.  This nltk module was faster than even html2text, though perhaps html2text is more robust.

```
betterHTML = html.decode(errors='ignore')
%timeit html2text.html2text(betterHTML)
%3.09 ms per loop
```

Comment: For anyone looking at this answer in the future, clean_html has been dropped for NLTK: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002076/python-nltk-clean-html-not-implemented

Answer (score 6):

Using BeautifulSoup the easiest way with less code to just get the strings, without empty lines and crap.

```
tag = <Parent_Tag_that_contains_the_data>
soup = BeautifulSoup(tag, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.stripped_strings:
    print repr(i)
```

Comment: By far the best and most forward answer, thank you!

Comment: Note, however that stripped_strings will include the page title which is not rendered on the page.

Comment: Reading further, I see that @polor beer's solution uses stripped_strings but corrects for the page title.

Answer (score 4):

If you care about performance, here's another more efficient way:

```
import re

INVISIBLE_ELEMS = ('style', 'script', 'head', 'title')
RE_SPACES = re.compile(r'\s{3,}')

def visible_texts(soup):
    """ get visible text from a document """
    text = ' '.join([
        s for s in soup.strings
        if s.parent.name not in INVISIBLE_ELEMS
    ])
    # collapse multiple spaces to two spaces.
    return RE_SPACES.sub('  ', text)
```

`soup.strings` is an iterator, and it returns `NavigableString` so that you can check the parent's tag name directly, without going through multiple loops.

Answer (score 3):

While, i would completely suggest using beautiful-soup in general, if anyone is looking to display the visible parts of a malformed html (e.g. where you have just a segment or line of a web-page) for whatever-reason, the the following will remove content between `<` and `>` tags:

```
import re   ## only use with malformed html - this is not efficient
def display_visible_html_using_re(text):             
    return(re.sub("(\<.*?\>)", "",text))
```

Answer (score 2):

The title is inside an `<nyt_headline>` tag, which is nested inside an `<h1>` tag and a `<div>` tag with id "article".

```
soup.findAll('nyt_headline', limit=1)
```

Should work.

The article body is inside an `<nyt_text>` tag, which is nested inside a `<div>` tag with id "articleBody".  Inside the `<nyt_text>`  element, the text itself is contained within `<p>`  tags.  Images are not within those `<p>` tags.  It's difficult for me to experiment with the syntax, but I expect a working scrape to look something like this.

```
text = soup.findAll('nyt_text', limit=1)[0]
text.findAll('p')
```

Comment: I'm sure this works for this test case however, looking for a more generic answer that may be applied to various other websites... So far, I've tried using regexps to find <script></script> tags and <!-- .* --> comments and replace them with "" but that's even proving kinda difficult for sum reason..

Answer (score 2):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment
import urllib.request
import re
import ssl

def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']:
        return False
    if isinstance(element, Comment):
        return False
    if re.match(r"[\n]+",str(element)): return False
    return True
def text_from_html(url):
    body = urllib.request.urlopen(url,context=ssl._create_unverified_context()).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(body ,"lxml")
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)  
    text = u",".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)
    text = text.lstrip().rstrip()
    text = text.split(',')
    clean_text = ''
    for sen in text:
        if sen:
            sen = sen.rstrip().lstrip()
            clean_text += sen+','
    return clean_text
url = 'http://www.nytimes.com/2009/12/21/us/21storm.html'
print(text_from_html(url))
```

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

*From the docs: [As of `Beautiful Soup` version 4.9.0, when `lxml` or `html.parser` are in use, the contents of `<script>`, `<style>`, and `<template>` tags are generally not considered to be ‘text’, since those tags are not part of the human-visible content of the page.](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)*

To get all the human readable text of the HTML `<body>` you can use [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text), to get rid of redundant whitespaces, etc. set strip parameter and join/separate all by a single whitespace:

```
import bs4, requests

response = requests.get('https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2022/09/13/us/politics/congress-stock-trading-investigation.html',headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0','cache-control': 'max-age=0'}, cookies={'cookies':''})
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

soup.article.get_text(' ', strip=True)
```

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

Comment: Does work for the example. Not for my case...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to handle this case is by using `getattr()`.  You can adapt this example to your needs:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source_html = """
<span class="ratingsDisplay">
    <a class="ratingNumber" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
        <span class="ratingsContent">3.7</span>
    </a>
</span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(source_html, "lxml")
my_ratings = getattr(soup.find('span', {"class": "ratingsContent"}), "text", None)
print(my_ratings)
```

This will find the text element,`"3.7"`, within the tag object `<span class="ratingsContent">3.7</span>` when it exists, however, default to `NoneType` when it does not.

> [`getattr(object, name[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x, 'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar. If the named attribute does not exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise, AttributeError is raised.