# BeautifulSoup: just get inside of a tag, no matter how many enclosing tags there are

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all the inner html from the `<p>` elements in a web page using BeautifulSoup. There are internal tags, but I don't care, I just want to get the internal text.

For example, for:

```
<p>Red</p>
<p><i>Blue</i></p>
<p>Yellow</p>
<p>Light <b>green</b></p>
```

How can I extract:

```
Red
Blue
Yellow
Light green
```

Neither `.string` nor `.contents[0]` does what I need. Nor does `.extract()`, because I don't want to have to specify the internal tags in advance - I want to deal with any that may occur.

Is there a 'just get the visible HTML' type of method in BeautifulSoup?

----UPDATE------

On advice, trying:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("test.html"))
p_tags = soup.findAll('p',text=True)
for i, p_tag in enumerate(p_tags): 
    print str(i) + p_tag
```

But that doesn't help - it prints out:

```
0Red
1

2Blue
3

4Yellow
5

6Light 
7green
8
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Short answer: `soup.findAll(text=True)`

This has already been answered, [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936466/beautifulsoup-grab-visible-webpage-text) and in the [BeautifulSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Advanced%20Topics).

**UPDATE:**

To clarify, a working piece of code:

```
>>> txt = """\
... <p>Red</p>
... <p><i>Blue</i></p>
... <p>Yellow</p>
... <p>Light <b>green</b></p>
... """
>>> import BeautifulSoup
>>> BeautifulSoup.__version__
'3.0.7a'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(txt)
>>> for node in soup.findAll('p'):
...     print ''.join(node.findAll(text=True))

Red
Blue
Yellow
Light green
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd looked at both those, but failed to extract the important bit of the StackOverflow question - and I find the BeautifulSoup documentation is only really useful if you already know what you're doing. Or maybe I just need more coffee.

Comment: print ''.join(soup.findAll(text=True))

Comment: I have added a working code example to illustrate how to use `.findAll(text=True)` to get what you want.

Comment: You can use 

`node.findAll(text=True)[0]` too

Comment: Consider this: `'<a href="http://abc.xyz.com/"><span>Business<i class="sample-class"></i></span></a>'` as data for BeautifulSoup(). It no longer works.

Comment: @AnkitBindal That HTML snippet doesn't contain a `<p>` tag, so the code in the answer has no chance of working. Your comment should have been posted as a separate question, though.

Comment: @AnkitBindal [You usually shouldn't use regular expressions to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/40076).

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer is great but it is 6 years old now, so here's the current [Beautiful Soup 4 version](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) of this answer:

```
>>> txt = """\
<p>Red</p>
<p><i>Blue</i></p>
<p>Yellow</p>
<p>Light <b>green</b></p>
"""
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, __version__
>>> __version__
'4.5.1'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, "html.parser")
>>> print("".join(soup.strings))

Red
Blue
Yellow
Light green
```

Answer (score 12):

I have stumbled upon this very same problem and wanted to share the 2019 version of this solution. Maybe it helps somebody out.

```
# importing the modules
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

# setting up your BeautifulSoup Object
webpage = urlopen("https://insertyourwebpage.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup( webpage.read(), features="lxml")
p_tags = soup.find_all('p')


for each in p_tags: 
    print (str(each.get_text()))
```

Notice that we're first printing the array content one by one and THEN call the get_text() method that strips the tags from the text, so that we only print out the text.

Also:

- it is better to use the updated 'find_all()' in bs4 than the older findAll()
- urllib2 was replaced by urllib.request and urllib.error, see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)

Now your output should be:

- Red
- Blue
- Yellow
- Light

Hope this helps someone looking for an updated solution.

Comment: Note that `//` is not how comments work in Python. Try adding working code :)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks for pointing it out. Have just changed it :)

Answer (score 4):

Normally the data scrapped from website will contains tags.To avoid that tags and show only text content, you can use text attribute.

For example,

```
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

    import urllib2 
    url = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.python.org")

    content = url.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

    title = soup.findAll("title")

    paragraphs = soup.findAll("p")

    print paragraphs[1] //Second paragraph with tags

    print paragraphs[1].text //Second paragraph without tags
```

In this example, I collect all paragraphs from python site and display it with tags and without tags.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the html to a string using `str`. Then, use the following code with your program:

```
import re
x = str(soup.find_all('p'))
content = str(re.sub("<.*?>", "", x))
```

This is called a `regex`. This one will remove anything that comes between two html tags (inclusive of the tags).