# How do I use BeautifulSoup to strip the <p> tags and just deliver the text back into the soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to replace any `<p>` tags with just the contents in my soup. This is in the middle of other processing that I'm doing using BeautifulSoup.

This is slightly different to [a similar question on extracting the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957013/beautifulsoup-just-get-inside-of-a-tag-no-matter-how-many-enclosing-tags-there).

Example input:

```
... </p> ... <p>Here is some text</p> ... and some more
```

Desired output:

```
... ... Here is some text ... and some more
```

And what would I do if I only want to do that processing in say a div of class="content"?

I don't yet seem to have my BeautifulSoup head on yet!

Comment: So far I like the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765848/remove-a-tag-using-beautifulsoup-but-keep-its-contents It looks promising.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't use beautifulSoup, but it should be similar to the built in HTMLParser library. This is a class I built to parse input html and convert the tags to a required different "markup".

```
class BaseHTMLProcessor(HTMLParser):
    def reset(self):                       
        # extend (called by HTMLParser.__init__)
        self.pieces = []
        HTMLParser.reset(self)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        # called for each start tag
        # attrs is a list of (attr, value) tuples
        # e.g. for <pre class="screen">, tag="pre", attrs=[("class", "screen")]
        # Ideally we would like to reconstruct original tag and attributes, but
        # we may end up quoting attribute values that weren't quoted in the source
        # document, or we may change the type of quotes around the attribute value
        # (single to double quotes).
        # Note that improperly embedded non-HTML code (like client-side Javascript)
        # may be parsed incorrectly by the ancestor, causing runtime script errors.
        # All non-HTML code must be enclosed in HTML comment tags (<!-- code -->)
        # to ensure that it will pass through this parser unaltered (in handle_comment).
        if tag == 'b': 
            v = r'%b[1]'
        elif tag == 'li': 
            v = r'%f[1]'
        elif tag == 'strong': 
            v = r'%b[1]%i[1]'
        elif tag == 'u': 
            v = r'%u[1]'
        elif tag == 'ul': 
            v = r'%n%'
        else:
            v = ''
        self.pieces.append("{0}".format(v))

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):         
        # called for each end tag, e.g. for </pre>, tag will be "pre"
        # Reconstruct the original end tag.
        if tag == 'li': 
            v = r'%f[0]' 
        elif tag == '/b': 
            v = r'%b[0]'
        elif tag == 'strong': 
            v = r'%b[0]%i[0]'
        elif tag == 'u': 
            v = r'%u[0]'
        elif tag == 'ul': 
            v = ''
        elif tag == 'br': 
            v = r'%n%' 
        else: 
            v = '' # it matched but we don't know what it is! assume it's invalid html and strip it
        self.pieces.append("{0}".format(v))

    def handle_charref(self, ref):         
        # called for each character reference, e.g. for "&#160;", ref will be "160"
        # Reconstruct the original character reference.
        self.pieces.append("&#%(ref)s;" % locals())

    def handle_entityref(self, ref):       
        # called for each entity reference, e.g. for "&copy;", ref will be "copy"
        # Reconstruct the original entity reference.
        self.pieces.append("&%(ref)s" % locals())
        # standard HTML entities are closed with a semicolon; other entities are not
        if htmlentitydefs.entitydefs.has_key(ref):
            self.pieces.append(";")

    def handle_data(self, text):           
        # called for each block of plain text, i.e. outside of any tag and
        # not containing any character or entity references
        # Store the original text verbatim.
        output = text.replace("\xe2\x80\x99","'").split('\r\n')
        for count,item in enumerate(output):
            output[count] = item.strip()
        self.pieces.append(''.join(output))

    def handle_comment(self, text):        
        # called for each HTML comment, e.g. <!-- insert Javascript code here -->
        # Reconstruct the original comment.
        # It is especially important that the source document enclose client-side
        # code (like Javascript) within comments so it can pass through this
        # processor undisturbed; see comments in unknown_starttag for details.
        self.pieces.append("<!--%(text)s-->" % locals())

    def handle_pi(self, text):             
        # called for each processing instruction, e.g. <?instruction>
        # Reconstruct original processing instruction.
        self.pieces.append("<?%(text)s>" % locals())

    def handle_decl(self, text):
        # called for the DOCTYPE, if present, e.g.
        # <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        #     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        # Reconstruct original DOCTYPE
        self.pieces.append("<!%(text)s>" % locals())

    def output(self):              
        """Return processed HTML as a single string"""
        return "".join(self.pieces)
```

To use the class, just source it. Then in your code use these lines:

```
parser = BaseHTMLProcessor()
for line in input:  
    parser.feed(line)
    parser.close()
    output = parser.output()
    parser.reset()
    print output
```

It works by tokenizing the input stream. Each piece of html that it comes to is dealt with in the appropriate method. So `<p><b>This is bold text!</b></p>` would trigger `handle_starttag` twice, then `handle_data` once, then `handle_endtag` twice. Finally, when the output method is called, it returns the stream contents joined back together.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, but I already have some BeautifulSoup code in place and I'm trying to remove some spurious and unreliable structure in the input. I'd prefer to use BS if possible.