# BeautifulSoup get_text from find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

This is my first work with web scraping. So far I am able to navigate and find the part of the HTML I want. I can print it as well. The problem is printing only the text, which will not work. I get following error, when trying it: `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get_text'`

Here my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

page = urllib.urlopen('some url')


soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
zeug = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'fm_linkeSpalte'}).get_text()


print zeug
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`find_all()` returns an array of elements. You should go through all of them and select that one you are need. And than call `get_text()`

**UPD**
For example:

```
    for el in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'fm_linkeSpalte'}):
        print el.get_text()
```

But note that you may have more than one element.

Comment: what is "el" and how should I define it?

Comment: @user193938 it is defined in for loop, `find_all` returns an array of elements, so `el` contains one of them on each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Try `for` inside the list for getting the data, like this:

```
zeug = [x.get_text() for x in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'fm_linkeSpalte'})]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
zeug = BeautifulSoup(str(soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'fm_linkeSpalte'})),features="lxml").get_text()

# explanation:
type(soup) #type "soup" is "bs4.BeautifulSoup"
zh1=soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'fm_linkeSpalte'})
type(zh1) #type "zh1" is "bs4.element.ResultSet"
# we need type of "zh1" "bs4.BeautifulSoup"
# next retype is not possible:
zh2 = BeautifulSoup(zh1) #this row is bug
# therefore now we retype "zh1" to string
zh2=str(zh1)
# and in next step we retype strng to "bs4.BeautifulSoup":
zh3=BeautifulSoup(zh2,features="lxml")
# the last step is:
zeug=zh3.get_text()
# theses all steps can be use in one line, see the first line
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I would close this issue for being a duplicate and link you to another I found that answers this question but I don't think I have the reputation needed to moderate... So...

[Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957013/beautifulsoup-just-get-inside-of-a-tag-no-matter-how-many-enclosing-tags-there)

Code for this:

```py
for el in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'fm_linkeSpalte'}):
    print ''.join(el.findAll(text=True))
```

If a mod wants to close this question that would be helpful.