# Python 2 Beautiful Soup, get text from all tags

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-2.x

Trying to get the text from all tags that have the class `task-topic-deprecated`, however I only seem to be able to get one.

Not a duplicate of [BeautifulSoup get_text from find_all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997587/beautifulsoup-get-text-from-find-all) - This issue uses multiple class names and so the working syntax is slightly different, `class_` as opposed to `attrs={'class':'`

Source page:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cfnetwork?language=objc

The output would be any string that is struckout on the page above:

```
CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing
kCFFTPResourceGroup
...etc
```

find_next() doesn't seem to move to the next item how I am expecting it to, and prints out the text I have already.

```
page = requests.get("https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cfnetwork?language=objc")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

aRow = soup.find('a', attrs={'class':'task-topic-deprecated has-adjacent-element symbol-name'}).get_text()
print aRow
bRow = soup.find('a', attrs={'class':'task-topic-deprecated has-adjacent-element symbol-name'}).find_next().get_text()
print bRow
cRow = soup.find('a', attrs={'class':'task-topic-deprecated has-adjacent-element symbol-name'}).find_next().find_next().get_text()
print cRow


CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing
CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing
CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing
```

Also tried putting it in a loop from various things I have found on Stack Overflow, but it seems to still only grab 1 item as per above.

Also tried with xPath, but this doesn't grab anything and prints out a blank list

```
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
allItems = tree.xpath('//a[@class="task-topic-deprecated has-adjacent-element symbol-name"]/text()')
print allItems
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have doing it wrong instead of `find` you can use `find_all` method to get result.

```
for i in soup.find_all('a', class_='task-topic-deprecated has-adjacent-element symbol-name'):
    print i.get_text()
```

May be this could help

Comment: That works, thanks. I'm sure I tried that though and got hit with Tracebacks. I was probably messing up the methods considering they keep changing between versions, find_next, findNext, nextSibling etc.
In which case, apologies for the duplicate!