# Processing all values of an array with get_text

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

(Disclaimer: I'm a newbie, I'm sorry if this problem is really obvious)

Hello,

I build a little script in order to first find certain parts of `HTML` markup within a local file and then display the information without `HTML` tags.

I used `bs4` and `find_all` / `get_text` for this. Take a look:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open("/Users/user1/Desktop/testdatapython.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "lxml")

titleResults = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'caption-subject'})

firstResult = titleResults[0]

firstStripped = firstResult.get_text()

print(firstStripped)
```

This actually works so far. But I want to do this for all values of `titleResults`, not only the first value. But I can't process an array with `get_text`.

Which way would be best to accomplish this? The number of values for `titleResults` is always changing since the local html file is only a sample.

Thank you in advance!

P.S. I already looked up this related thread but it is not enough for understanding or solving the problem sadly:

[BeautifulSoup get_text from find_all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997587/beautifulsoup-get-text-from-find-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find_all returns a list

```
for result in titleResults:
    stripped = result.get_text()
    print(stripped)
```

Comment: @PascalL. All the Best!