# BeautifulSoup: `find_all` and `get_text`

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have some xml that is formatted like this:

```
  <Paragraph Type="Character">
   <Text>
    TED
   </Text>
  </Paragraph>
  <Paragraph Type="Dialogue">
   <Text>
    I thought we had a rule against that.
   </Text>
  </Paragraph>
  <Paragraph Type="Character">
   <Text>
    ANNIE
   </Text>
  </Paragraph>
  <Paragraph Type="Dialogue">
   <Text>
    ...oh.
```

I'm trying to extract the data so that it looks like this:

```
Character   Dialogue

TED         I thought we had a rule against that.
ANNIE       ...oh.
```

I've been trying with:

```
soup.find(Type = "Character").get_text()
soup.find(Type = "Dialogue").get_text()
```

which will return one line at a time. When I try to do more than one, with `soup.find_all`, i.e.:

```
soup.find_all(Type = "Character").get_text()
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

I understand that `find_all()` returns an array of elements (thanks to this previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21997788/8742237), and that I should select one element in the array, but I would like to get all of the elements in the array into the format I showed above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get pairs of `Character` and `Dialogue`, you can use `zip()` method:

```
html_data = '''  <Paragraph Type="Character">
   <Text>
    TED
   </Text>
  </Paragraph>
  <Paragraph Type="Dialogue">
   <Text>
    I thought we had a rule against that.
   </Text>
  </Paragraph>
  <Paragraph Type="Character">
   <Text>
    ANNIE
   </Text>
  </Paragraph>
  <Paragraph Type="Dialogue">
   <Text>
    ...oh.
   </Text>
  </Paragraph>
  '''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')

print('{: <10} {}'.format('Character', 'Dialogue'))
print()
for character, dialogue in zip(soup.select('[Type="Character"]'), soup.select('[Type="Character"] + [Type="Dialogue"]')):
    print('{: <10} {}'.format( character.get_text(strip=True), dialogue.get_text(strip=True)) )
```

Prints:

```
Character  Dialogue

TED        I thought we had a rule against that.
ANNIE      ...oh.
```

---

The CSS selector `[Type="Character"] + [Type="Dialogue"]` will select tag with `Type=Dialogue` that is placed immediately after tag with `Type=Character`

More here : [CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: For anyone struggling with this question in the future, the CSS Selectors Reference link above is excellent.

Comment: I'm still trying to get my head around this one, as I'm still learning and Googling every command. If I want to save the output in a list or zip object is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: It's okay, I've figured it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried looping over the array and getting the text like that?

```
[x.get_text() for x in soup.find_all(Type = "Character")]
```

The array doesn't have the get_text() attribute, but the elements should.

Comment: That works very well, and I will look into extracting everything via loops. Would you have any suggestions on how to pair the `Dialogue` text with the  `Character` text that immediately precedes it, as in the desired output I showed above?

Comment: I wouldn't use `find_all()` in that case because you now have two separate lists of paragraphs and these might not be perfectly correlated. Instead, use `find()` to get the first paragraph, then use `next_sibling` to move to the next in a `while` loop. Check the type of each paragraph to decide how to format it.

Comment: just create character list and then dialogue lists and do list(zip(character list, dialogue list)) assuming the lists would be of the same length. this would pair them

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Andrej Kesely is exactly what I was looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57484760/8742237

Just in case anyone looking at this question in the future is a beginner, this my attempt to break it down:

```
list1 = [x.get_text(strip = True) for x in soup.select('[Type="Character"]')]
print(list1)

list2 = [x.get_text(strip = True) for x in soup.select('[Type="Dialogue"]')]
print(list2)

zip1 = zip(list1, list2)
print(list(zip1))
```