# Getting the text from links inside a td with BeautifulSoup in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get `BeautifulSoup` capture a **list of all of the location names** through scraping, I used to use the following:

```
locs = LOOPED.findAll("td", {"class": "max use"})
```

Which used to work for the HTML

```
<td class="max use" style="">London</td>
```

However the HTML has changed to and it's no longer returning **`London`**

```
<td class="max use" style="">
    <div class="notranslate">
        <span><a data-title="View Location" href="/location/uk/gb/london/">London</a></span> <span class="extra hidden">(DEFAULT)</span>
    </div>
</td>
```

**Edit:** If I print locs, I get a list like:

`<td class="max use" style="">\n<div class="notranslate">\n<span><a data-title="View Location" href="/location/uk/gb/london/">London</a></span> <span class="extra hidden">(DEFAULT)</span>\n</div>\n</td>, <td class="max use" style="">\n<div class="notranslate">\n<span><a data-title="View Location" href="/location/uk/gb/manchester/">Manchester</a></span> <span class="extra hidden">(DEFAULT)</span>\n</div>\n</td>, <td class="max use" style="">\n<div class="notranslate">\n<span><a data-title="View Location" href="/location/uk/gb/liverpool/">Liverpool</a></span> <span class="extra hidden">(NA)</span>\n</div>\n</td>]`

Which as you can see has 3 different locations, from the above I would expect to see a list of `[London, Manchester, Liverpool]`

I thought that I should be using something like:

```
locs = LOOPED.findAll("td", {"class": "max use"})
locs = locs.findAll('a')[1]
print locs.text
```

But this only retuns with

> AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'findAll'

I can't work out how to get the `Beautifulsoup` to re-search for the a hyperlink text...

Comment: Is it not because your 'a' is not directly under 'td', I guess you need to go through 'div' then 'span' first.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, if I print `locs` after `locs = LOOPED.findAll("td", {"class": "max use"})` it prints the HTML that has the link under a `div` & `span`.

Comment: Hey, the issue here is that `locs` is a `list`. If text from each location in `locs` is needed, you'll have to loop over `locs` and print the text in each of the locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
tag = LOOPED.findAll('td') #all "td" tag in a list
tag_a = tag[0].find('a')
print tag_a.text
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me, it needs to search for the `max use` class first and then look for the `a`

Answer (score 1):

A method more robust to future HTML structure changes is to get all of the text inside each `td` element, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2957181/40076):

```
locs = LOOPED.findAll("td", {"class": "max use"})
for loc in locs:
    print ''.join(loc.findAll(text=True))
```