# Beautiful Soup: get contents of search result tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to get the contents of this type of html snippet using beautiful soup (it is a "tag" object).

```
<span class="font5"> arrives at this calculation from the Torah’s report that the deluge (rains) began on the 17<sup>th</sup> day of the second month </span>
```

I've tried:

```
soup.contents.find_all('span')
soup.find_all('span')
soup.find_all(re.compile("font[0-9]+"))
soup.string
soup.child
```

And none of these seem to be working. What can I do?

Comment: Are you saying `soup.find_all('span')` finds nothing, too much or finds some but not including what you want?

Comment: all of these either return nothing or error.

Comment: Well then what you looking for is not in the source.

Answer (score 2):

`soup.find_all('span')` does work; returns all `span` tags.

If you want to get `span` tag with `font<N>` class, specify the pattern as a keyword argument `class_`:

```
soup.find_all('span', class_=re.compile('font[0-9]+'))
```

Comment: both of these return [], no contents... Please note that this is a tag object, not a soup object.

Comment: @EsterLin, Could you provide the minimal working code that reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If starting with  *font* is unique enough you can use also use a *css selector* looking for the class starting with font:

```
soup.select("span[class^=font]")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ''.join(soup.findAll(text=True))
```

(answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957013/beautifulsoup-just-get-inside-of-a-tag-no-matter-how-many-enclosing-tags-there))