# how to print only text beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn how beautifulsoup works in order to create an application.

I am able to find and print all elements with .find_all() however they print the html tags as well. How can I print ONLY the text within these tags.

This is what I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

"""<html>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('index.html'), "html.parser")
i = soup.find_all('p')
print i
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using BeautifulSoup Extract Text without Tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380171/using-beautifulsoup-extract-text-without-tags)

Comment: @franklinsijo Yeah. I also linked another of the same question in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may help you:-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
source_code = """<html>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)
print soup.text
```

Output:-

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('index.html'), "html.parser")
i = soup.find_all('p')
for p in i:
    print p.text
```

`find_all()` will return a list of tag, you should iterate over it and use `tag.text` to get the text under the tag

Better way:

```
for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    print p.text
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what they do in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957013/beautifulsoup-just-get-inside-of-a-tag-no-matter-how-many-enclosing-tags-there). Use `findAll(text=True)`. So in your code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

"""<html>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('index.html'), "html.parser")
i = soup.findAll(text=True)
print i
```

Comment: this will return all the text in the HTML code including comment, this is definitely not a solution

Comment: including comment? Do you mean including comments?

Comment: The `Comment` object is just a special type of `NavigableString`