# does BeautifulSoup strips inline CSS and javascript content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

hey guys does beautifulSoup strips css and javascript content? after using

```
content3 = ''.join(BeautifulSoup(content).findAll(text=True))
```

i still have them lingering around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you want to strip, all script and style elements?  It should be something like:

```
''.join(BeautifulSoup(content).findAll(text=lambda text: 
text.parent.name != "script" and 
text.parent.name != "style"))
```

Comment: thats right, probably a regex replace could do that, but i was wondering if beautifulsoup handles tthat. Or does the "simple version of webstemmer" could do that too?