# Converting html to text with Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, text, beautifulsoup

I am trying to convert an html block to text using Python.

**Input:**

```
<div class="body"><p><strong></strong></p>
<p><strong></strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa</p>
<p>Consectetuer adipiscing elit. <a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank" class="source">Some Link</a> Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa</p>
<p>Aenean massa.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa</p>
<p>Consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa</p></div>
```

**Desired output:**

> Lorem
> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
> ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
>
> Consectetuer adipiscing elit.
> Some
> Link Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
>
> Aenean
> massa.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
> commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit
> amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
> Aenean massa
>
> Consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
> ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa

I tried the `html2text` module without much success:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib2
import html2text
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/page.html').read())

txt = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'body'})

print(html2text.html2text(txt))
```

The `txt` object produces the html block above. I'd like to convert it to text and print it on the screen.

Comment: Do you have to use Python? `lynx -dump filename.html` will do this. http://lynx.browser.org/ Also, you could use an XPath expression and http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

`soup.get_text()` outputs what you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.get_text())
```

output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
Consectetuer adipiscing elit. Some Link Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
Aenean massa.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
Consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
```

To keep newlines:

```
print(soup.get_text('\n'))
```

To be identical to your example, you can replace a newline with two newlines:

```
soup.get_text().replace('\n','\n\n')
```

Comment: soup.get_text() is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: BeautifulSoup 4 only, unfortunately.

Comment: This saved my day! I update the response to for Python3 and incorporating @t-8ch's newline idea.

Answer (score 41):

It's possible using python standard [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html):

```python
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class HTMLFilter(HTMLParser):
    text = ""
    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.text += data

f = HTMLFilter()
f.feed(data)
print(f.text)
```

Comment: This answer works great with no 3rd party package dependencies! my PyCharm editor hinted at me that I will need to use ABC mixin so that it get rid off the all abstract methods need to be implemented error. https://gist.github.com/ye/050e898fbacdede5a6155da5b3db078d

Comment: Note that initializing the `text` class attribute and assigning the `self.text` instance attribute is un-Pythonic, but does work here due to the reassignment. If one was to e.g. use a mutable list instead (`pieces = []` and `self.pieces.append(data)`), all instances of the class would share the same list object.

Comment: Great answer! Although `html` is not available as part of the python2 standard library. So this solution only works for python3.

Comment: I get some javascript in the returned text but standard lib only is still nice

Comment: I'm getting "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "AttribAccessDict") to str" with this now

Comment: This doesn't work if there is invalid closing of html tag, though beautifulsoup works well for that case.

Answer (score 10):

The main problem is how you keep some basic formatting. Here is my own minimal approach to keep new lines and bullets. I am sure it's not the solution to everything you want to keep but  it's a starting point:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse_html(html):
    elem = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    text = ''
    for e in elem.descendants:
        if isinstance(e, str):
            text += e.strip()
        elif e.name in ['br',  'p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4','tr', 'th']:
            text += '\n'
        elif e.name == 'li':
            text += '\n- '
    return text
```

The above adds a new line for `'br',  'p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4','tr', 'th'`
and a new line with `-` in front of text for `li` elements

Answer (score 8):

You can use a regular expression, but it's not recommended.  The following code removes all the HTML tags in your data, giving you the text:

```
import re

data = """<div class="body"><p><strong></strong></p>
<p><strong></strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa</p>
<p>Consectetuer adipiscing elit. <a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank" class="source">Some Link</a> Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa</p>
<p>Aenean massa.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa</p>
<p>Consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa</p></div>"""

data = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', data)

print(data)
```

**Output**

> ```
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
> Consectetuer adipiscing elit. Some Link Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
> Aenean massa.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
> Consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
> ```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags ;-)

Comment: @DaveJarvis Lol... here the OP doesn't want to do anything with HTML as such, he just wants the HTML plucked out altogether.

Comment: Still, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/517371 is very much relevant. There are more things wrong with `/<.*?>/` than I could possibly enumerate here in 600 characters.

Answer (score 6):

The `'\n'` places a newline between the paragraphs.

```
from bs4 import Beautifulsoup

soup = Beautifulsoup(text)
print(soup.get_text('\n'))
```

Comment: In also places newlines in the middle of sentences if you have e.g. `"<p>That's <strong>not</strong> what I want</p>"`

Comment: I still see XML elements in the output (although those are not strict HTML elements, like `[if gte mso 9]><xml><o:OfficeDocumentSettings><o:AllowPNG></o:AllowPNG>...` . How can I filter those out also?

Comment: I also want to convert any HTML characters, like `&nbsp;` or `&copy;`

Comment: Same issue as @CsabaToth here.

Answer (score 5):

I liked @FrBrGeorge's *no dependency* answer so much that I expanded it to only extract the `body` tag and added a convenience method so that HTML to text is a single line:

```
from abc import ABC
from html.parser import HTMLParser


class HTMLFilter(HTMLParser, ABC):
    """
    A simple no dependency HTML -> TEXT converter.
    Usage:
          str_output = HTMLFilter.convert_html_to_text(html_input)
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.text = ''
        self.in_body = False
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag: str, attrs):
        if tag.lower() == "body":
            self.in_body = True

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag.lower() == "body":
            self.in_body = False

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.in_body:
            self.text += data

    @classmethod
    def convert_html_to_text(cls, html: str) -> str:
        f = cls()
        f.feed(html)
        return f.text.strip()
```

See comment for usage.

This converts all of the text inside the `body`, which in theory could include `style` and `script` tags.  Further filtering could be achieved by extending the pattern of as shown for `body` -- i.e. setting instance variables `in_style` or `in_script`.

Answer (score 4):

There are some nice things here, and i might as well throw in my solution:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
def _handle_data(self, data):
    self.text += data + '\n'

HTMLParser.handle_data = _handle_data

def get_html_text(html: str):
    parser = HTMLParser()
    parser.text = ''
    parser.feed(html)

    return parser.text.strip()
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a library called [inscripts](https://github.com/weblyzard/inscriptis) really simple and light and can get its input from a file or directly from an URL:

```
from inscriptis import get_text
text = get_text(html)
print(text)
```

The output is:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
> commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
>
> Consectetuer adipiscing elit. Some Link Aenean commodo ligula eget
> dolor. Aenean massa
>
> Aenean massa.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
> elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
> commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
>
> Consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
> Aenean massa

Comment: To all, This answer came ~9 years after the question, but as I go through the various answers here, and other other similar questions (and have tried beautiful soup variations too), this one seems the best so far BY FAR.

Answer (score 2):

[gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho) might be a good choice for this!

Input:

```py
from gazpacho import Soup

html = """\
<div class="body"><p><strong></strong></p>
<p><strong></strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa</p>
<p>Consectetuer adipiscing elit. <a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank" class="source">Some Link</a> Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa</p>
<p>Aenean massa.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa</p>
<p>Consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa</p></div>
"""
```

Output:

```py
text = Soup(html).strip(whitespace=False) # to keep "\n" characters intact
print(text)
```

> ```
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
> Consectetuer adipiscing elit. Some Link Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
> Aenean massa.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
> Consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I was in need of a way of doing this on a client's system without having to download additional libraries. I never found a good solution, so I created my own. Feel free to use this if you like.

```
import urllib 

def html2text(strText):
    str1 = strText
    int2 = str1.lower().find("<body")
    if int2>0:
       str1 = str1[int2:]
    int2 = str1.lower().find("</body>")
    if int2>0:
       str1 = str1[:int2]
    list1 = ['<br>',  '<tr',  '<td', '</p>', 'span>', 'li>', '</h', 'div>' ]
    list2 = [chr(13), chr(13), chr(9), chr(13), chr(13),  chr(13), chr(13), chr(13)]
    bolFlag1 = True
    bolFlag2 = True
    strReturn = ""
    for int1 in range(len(str1)):
      str2 = str1[int1]
      for int2 in range(len(list1)):
        if str1[int1:int1+len(list1[int2])].lower() == list1[int2]:
           strReturn = strReturn + list2[int2]
      if str1[int1:int1+7].lower() == '<script' or str1[int1:int1+9].lower() == '<noscript':
         bolFlag1 = False
      if str1[int1:int1+6].lower() == '<style':
         bolFlag1 = False
      if str1[int1:int1+7].lower() == '</style':
         bolFlag1 = True
      if str1[int1:int1+9].lower() == '</script>' or str1[int1:int1+11].lower() == '</noscript>':
         bolFlag1 = True
      if str2 == '<':
         bolFlag2 = False
      if bolFlag1 and bolFlag2 and (ord(str2) != 10) :
        strReturn = strReturn + str2
      if str2 == '>':
         bolFlag2 = True
      if bolFlag1 and bolFlag2:
        strReturn = strReturn.replace(chr(32)+chr(13), chr(13))
        strReturn = strReturn.replace(chr(9)+chr(13), chr(13))
        strReturn = strReturn.replace(chr(13)+chr(32), chr(13))
        strReturn = strReturn.replace(chr(13)+chr(9), chr(13))
        strReturn = strReturn.replace(chr(13)+chr(13), chr(13))
    strReturn = strReturn.replace(chr(13), '\n')
    return strReturn


url = "http://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/sep/25/us-air-strikes-islamic-state-oil-isis"    
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()    
print html2text(html)
```

Comment: The reason for downvote is the improper indentation. As the code has a medium complexity. It's a little hard to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use BeautifulSoup to remove unwanted scripts and similar, though you may need to experiment with a few different sites to make sure you've covered the different types of things you wish to exclude.  Try this:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
response = get('http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/health/2284783.stm')
soup = BS(response.content, "html.parser")
for child in soup.body.children:
   if child.name == 'script':
       child.decompose() 
print(soup.body.get_text())
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally like Gazpacho solution by [emehex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64286995/2424880), but it only use regular expression for filtering out the tags. No more magic. This means that solution keep text inside <style> and <script>.

So I would rather implement a simple solution based on regular expressions and use standard Python 3.4 library for unescape HTML entities:

```
import re
from html import unescape

def html_to_text(html):

    # use non-greedy for remove scripts and styles
    text = re.sub("<script.*?</script>", "", html, flags=re.DOTALL)
    text = re.sub("<style.*?</style>", "", text, flags=re.DOTALL)

    # remove other tags
    text = re.sub("<[^>]+>", " ", text)

    # strip whitespace
    text = " ".join(text.split())

    # unescape html entities
    text = unescape(text)

    return text
```

Of course, this does not error prove as BeautifulSoup or other parsers solutions. But you don't need any 3rd party package.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know who wrote this [Library](https://pypi.org/project/html2text/) but, bless his/her heart.

Answer (score 1):

An updated answer based on Andreas' answer.

```
def parse_html(html):
    elem = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    text = ''
    for e in elem.descendants:
        if isinstance(e, str):
            text += e.get_text().strip()
        elif e.name in ['span']:
            text += ' '
        elif e.name in ['br',  'p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'tr', 'th', 'div']:
            text += '\n'
        elif e.name == 'li':
            text += '\n- '
    return text
```

Why? Some XML code was still leaking inside, spans were stripped and didnt have enough space, and divs sometimes require more line breaks. Everything else is the same.

Answer (score 0):

A two-step [**`lxml`**](https://lxml.de/)-based approach with markup sanitizing before converting to plain text.

The script accepts either a path to an HTML file or piped stdin.

Will remove script blocks and all possibly undesired text. You can configure the [lxml Cleaner](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.clean.Cleaner-class.html) instance to suit your needs.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from lxml import html
from lxml.html import tostring
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner


def sanitize(dirty_html):
    cleaner = Cleaner(page_structure=True,
                  meta=True,
                  embedded=True,
                  links=True,
                  style=True,
                  processing_instructions=True,
                  inline_style=True,
                  scripts=True,
                  javascript=True,
                  comments=True,
                  frames=True,
                  forms=True,
                  annoying_tags=True,
                  remove_unknown_tags=True,
                  safe_attrs_only=True,
                  safe_attrs=frozenset(['src','color', 'href', 'title', 'class', 'name', 'id']),
                  remove_tags=('span', 'font', 'div')
                  )

    return cleaner.clean_html(dirty_html)


if len(sys.argv) > 1:
  fin = open(sys.argv[1], encoding='utf-8')
else:
  fin = sys.stdin

source = fin.read()
source = sanitize(source)
source = source.replace('<br>', '\n')

tree = html.fromstring(source)
plain = tostring(tree, method='text', encoding='utf-8')

print(plain.decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem using Scrapy you may try adding this to settings.py

```
#settings.py
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from lxml import html as html_module


def html_2_text(html_content):
    tree = html_module.fromstring(html_content)
    # text_list = tree.xpath('//text()')
    # text_list = tree.xpath('//text()[not(ancestor::script)]')
    text_list = tree.xpath('//text()[not(ancestor::script) and normalize-space()]')
    text_list = [text.strip() for text in text_list]
    return "\n".join(text for text in text_list if text!="")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class HTMLFilter(HTMLParser):
    text = ''
    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.text += f'{data}\n'

def html2text(html):
    filter = HTMLFilter()
    filter.feed(html)

    return filter.text

content = html2text(content_temp)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).