# How to change html to text in python?

Tags: python, html

```
htmldoc.text
```

html tags are ignored.
I want pretty print for html tags such as
table , br.

What easy way are you using to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting html to text with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694482/converting-html-to-text-with-python)

Comment: Ok,  sorry.  I will see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```