# Convert HTML to readable text

Tags: javascript, html

In mongo data is saved as

```html
<div>Dear Customer,</div><div>An amount of Rs. <a data-value="Payment - Amount to Pay" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.amount_to_pay_3xkhkenphf">@Payment - Amount to Pay</a> for your Loan Account Number <a data-value="Payment - Loan Number" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.loan_number_rtcivc45ok">@Payment - Loan Number</a> has been received on <a data-value="Payment - Date" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.payment_date">@Payment - Date</a> ,vide receipt no <a data-value="Payment - Receipt Number" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.receipt_number_5dow863ae">@Payment - Receipt Number</a>.</div>
<div>Payment Mode: <a data-value="Payment - Payment Mode" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.payment_mode_chw0gfq6vo">@Payment - Payment Mode</a>.</div>
<div>Please find the receipt attached below.</div>
```

So when I want to send the email via an external API, in the body I am reading the value from mongo db and  directly sending it.

So the in the mail, body is going as

```html
<div>Dear Customer,</div>
<div>An amount of Rs. <a data-value="Payment - Amount to Pay" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.amount_to_pay_3xkhkenphf">@Payment - Amount to Pay</a> for your Loan Account Number <a data-value="Payment - Loan Number" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.loan_number_rtcivc45ok">@Payment - Loan Number</a> has been received on <a data-value="Payment - Date" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.payment_date">@Payment - Date</a> ,vide receipt no <a data-value="Payment - Receipt Number" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.receipt_number_5dow863ae">@Payment - Receipt Number</a>.</div>
<div>Payment Mode: <a data-value="Payment - Payment Mode" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.payment_mode_chw0gfq6vo">@Payment - Payment Mode</a>.</div>
<div>Please find the receipt attached below.</div>
```

However, I need to send it like this

```txt
Dear Customer, An amount of Rs. 111 for your Loan Account Number 8204221103679 has been received on 24-Jul-2023 ,vide receipt no 1690195463903291.Payment Mode: Cash. Please find the receipt attached below.
```

How can I modify it?

Comment: Why do you need to? Email can be sent as HTML, so to the receiver it looks like normal text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can get the text of a div tag using only javascript (no jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370204/how-can-get-the-text-of-a-div-tag-using-only-javascript-no-jquery)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting html to text with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694482/converting-html-to-text-with-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `DOMParser` API to convert HTML to text. Here's how:

```js
var html = `
   <div>Dear Customer,</div>
<div>An amount of Rs. <a data-value="Payment - Amount to Pay" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.amount_to_pay_3xkhkenphf">@Payment - Amount to Pay</a> for your Loan Account Number <a data-value="Payment - Loan Number" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.loan_number_rtcivc45ok">@Payment - Loan Number</a> has been received on <a data-value="Payment - Date" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.payment_date">@Payment - Date</a> ,vide receipt no <a data-value="Payment - Receipt Number" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.receipt_number_5dow863ae">@Payment - Receipt Number</a>.</div>
<div>Payment Mode: <a data-value="Payment - Payment Mode" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.payment_mode_chw0gfq6vo">@Payment - Payment Mode</a>.</div>
<div>Please find the receipt attached below.</div>
    `;

    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    var text = doc.body.textContent || "";
    console.log(text);


 //or use the values from html use the id and getelement by id or tag

 //let values = {
 // "@Payment - Amount to Pay": document.getElementById('amountToPay').value,
 // "@Payment - Loan Number": document.getElementById('loanNumber').value,
 // "@Payment - Date": document.getElementById('paymentDate').value,
//  "@Payment - Receipt Number": document.getElementById('receiptNumber').value,
 // "@Payment - Payment Mode": document.getElementById('paymentMode').value
//};

let values = {
  "@Payment - Amount to Pay": "111",
  "@Payment - Loan Number": "8204221103679",
  "@Payment - Date": "24-Jul-2023",
  "@Payment - Receipt Number": "1690195463903291",
  "@Payment - Payment Mode": "Cash"
};

for (let key in values) {
  let regex = new RegExp(key, "g");
  html = html.replace(regex, values[key]);
}
 
var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    var text = doc.body.textContent || "";
    console.log(text);
```

This is how you can read HTML file

```js
// Get the entire HTML of the page including <script> tags
var htmlWithScripts = document.documentElement.outerHTML;

// Create a new DOMParser
var parser = new DOMParser();

// Parse the HTML string into a new document object
var doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlWithScripts, 'text/html');

// Get all script tags
var scripts = doc.getElementsByTagName('script');

// Loop through the script tags and remove each one
for (let i = scripts.length; i--;) {
  scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
}

// Get the updated HTML string without <script> tags
var htmlWithoutScripts = doc.documentElement.outerHTML;

// Print the HTML string without <script> tags
 

 

var html = htmlWithoutScripts;
  var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    var text = doc.body.textContent || "";
    console.log(text);


 //or use the values from html use the id and getelement by id or tag

 //let values = {
 // "@Payment - Amount to Pay": document.getElementById('amountToPay').value,
 // "@Payment - Loan Number": document.getElementById('loanNumber').value,
 // "@Payment - Date": document.getElementById('paymentDate').value,
//  "@Payment - Receipt Number": document.getElementById('receiptNumber').value,
 // "@Payment - Payment Mode": document.getElementById('paymentMode').value
//};

let values = {
  "@Payment - Amount to Pay": "111",
  "@Payment - Loan Number": "8204221103679",
  "@Payment - Date": "24-Jul-2023",
  "@Payment - Receipt Number": "1690195463903291",
  "@Payment - Payment Mode": "Cash"
};

for (let key in values) {
  let regex = new RegExp(key, "g");
  html = html.replace(regex, values[key]);
}
 
var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    var text = doc.body.textContent || "";
    console.log(text);
```

```html
   <div>Dear Customer,</div>
<div>An amount of Rs. <a data-value="Payment - Amount to Pay" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.amount_to_pay_3xkhkenphf">@Payment - Amount to Pay</a> for your Loan Account Number <a data-value="Payment - Loan Number" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.loan_number_rtcivc45ok">@Payment - Loan Number</a> has been received on <a data-value="Payment - Date" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.payment_date">@Payment - Date</a> ,vide receipt no <a data-value="Payment - Receipt Number" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.receipt_number_5dow863ae">@Payment - Receipt Number</a>.</div>
<div>Payment Mode: <a data-value="Payment - Payment Mode" data-mention="" class="wysiwyg-mention" href="payment_new.payment_mode_chw0gfq6vo">@Payment - Payment Mode</a>.</div>
<div>Please find the receipt attached below.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your HTML code to pure text, by using `DOMParser`, or by creating an element, setting its `innerHTML` property to the code and then getting the string by the `innerText` property.

Like this:

```
var code = 'Apple is a <span style="color: red">red</span> colored fruit';

var tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = code;
var result = tmp.innerText;

console.log(result);
// --> Apple is a red colored fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to display the whole text without any linebreaks, a simple solution would be to insert a `<style>` tag in the head of the mail that contains

```
div {
  display: inline;
}
```