# How to save web page as text file?

Tags: python, web, text, save

I would like to save a web page (all content) as a text file. (As if you did right click on webpage -> "Save Page As" -> "Save as text file" and not as html file)

I have tried using the following code:

```
import urllib2
url=''
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
page_content = page.read()
file = open('file_text.txt', 'w')
f.write(page_content)
f.close()
```

My goal is to be able to save a whole text without html code.
(for example i would like read "è" instead "&eacute")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendered HTML to plain text using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337528/rendered-html-to-plain-text-using-python)

Comment: One thing - you open 'file', but write and close 'f'. Name needs to be consistent.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [html2text](https://github.com/aaronsw/html2text) as mentioned [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13337885/1342445)

```
import urllib2
import html2text
url=''
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html_content = page.read()
rendered_content = html2text.html2text(html_content)
file = open('file_text.txt', 'w')
file.write(rendered_content)
file.close()
```

Comment: Hi pnovotnak, Thank you! 
I saw the library html2text but when i do "import" it returns an error.
`import html2text  ~
ImportError: No module named html2text`

I use python 2.7 on windows and I can not understand how I can add the library "html2text" for obtain a correct use. (I tried also with python 3.5 but i had the same problem)

Comment: No worries :) You need to install it, since it's not part of the standard Python library. See here: http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing/

Comment: I'm getting the error **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'** on the line *rendered_content = html2text...*