# How to get a line of the source Code of a Website in Python?

Tags: python

How to get the line x of the source Code of a Website?

I Need a function like this:

> > > def source_code(URL, line):
> > >                ...

Comment: Open up a http request, parse the response and return line number x? Check out the requests or urllib3 python modules

Comment: I recommend you take a look -> Beautifulsoup

Comment: *I need a function like this*. Then start your favorite code editor and start writing one. This isn't a code writing service. Make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. If you run into difficulties, you can then explain the problem you've encountered, include the *relevant* portions of your code, and ask a specific question about that code. See [ask].

Answer (score 3):

use request module

```
import requests as req
url = '"http://www.something.com"'
resp = req.get(url)
print(resp.text) # html response
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard library module in python: **urllib2**, you could also check out **python-requests**
Try the following then:

```
import urllib2
resp = urllib2.urlopen("The URL of the webpage whose source code you want")
```

Now go through https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ , this is BeautifulSoup, which you can use for parsing. You can just set the condition of which line to retrieve using it.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
import requests

def source_code(url, line):
    # get the page source code and split each line 
    lines = requests.get(url).text.split('\n')

    # page source code had too few lines
    if len(lines) < line : return ''
    else: return lines[line-1]


print(source_code('somepageurl', 9))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can save the HTML content of a page, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166169/how-to-save-web-page-as-text-file-python), and 
go to line using the file's functions:

```
    file_awesome = open('saved_html.html', 'r')
    content = file_awesome.readlines()
    print(content[7])
```