# BeatifulSoup4 get_text still has javascript

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nltk

I'm trying to remove all the html/javascript using bs4, however, it doesn't get rid of javascript. I still see it there with the text. How can I get around this?

I tried using `nltk` which works fine however, `clean_html` and `clean_url` will be removed moving forward. Is there a way to use soups `get_text` and get the same result?

I tried looking at these other pages:

[BeautifulSoup get_text does not strip all tags and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524387/beautifulsoup-get-text-does-not-strip-all-tags-and-javascript)

Currently i'm using the nltk's deprecated functions.

**EDIT**

Here's an example:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.cnn.com"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.get_text()
```

I still see the following for CNN:

```
$j(function() {
"use strict";
if ( window.hasOwnProperty('safaripushLib') && window.safaripushLib.checkEnv() ) {
var pushLib = window.safaripushLib,
current = pushLib.currentPermissions();
if (current === "default") {
pushLib.checkPermissions("helloClient", function() {});
}
}
});

/*globals MainLocalObj*/
$j(window).load(function () {
'use strict';
MainLocalObj.init();
});
```

How can I remove the js?

Only other options I found are:

https://github.com/aaronsw/html2text

The problem with `html2text` is that it's really *really* slow at times, and creates noticable lag, which is one thing nltk was always very good with.

Comment: It would really help if we could see (a section of) the html including javascript

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Based partly on [Can I remove script tags with BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598524/can-i-remove-script-tags-with-beautifulsoup)

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.cnn.com"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.decompose()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

print(text)
```

Comment: instead of `script.extract()`, it's better to use `script.decompose()` which only deletes without returning the tag object.

Comment: That is a lot of data structures you're building just so you don't have to write `re.sub("[ \n\r\t]{2,}", " ", text)` :)

Comment: @badp Especially that you can just say `soup.get_text(" ", strip=True)` ?

Comment: @CsabaToth, @badp, you actually don't want to use  `strip=True` because it will cause strings to be concatenated incorrectly. It's important to preserve them, then use `splitlines`, then sanitize each individual string.

Comment: @HughBothwell, still not able to stop script tags completely Eg. [here](https://pastebin.com/h0uV3b8V)

Comment: For people curious, `soup(['script', 'style'])` is identical to `soup.find_all(['script', 'style'])`, as explained in `help(soup.__call__)`.

Answer (score 10):

To prevent encoding errors at the end...

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = url
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

print(text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: still not able to stop script tags completely Eg. [here](https://pastebin.com/h0uV3b8V)