# how merge string to open webpage

Tags: python

I want everytime people go to my website, it will automatically redirect to another website, say:

```
https://www.redirect.com/link?q=NEWSTRING
```

it sounds weird, but actually, what I want is when people load my page, it will trigger some scripts, in which it can tract "NEWSTRING" from some website, then put it to the link above to redirect my website there.
So what I have is a first part of the link, which is fixed:

```
https://www.redirect.com/link?q=
```

then

```
NEWSTRING
```

is obtained from my script, now how to write some thing that will redirect the webpage?
What I can think of is, write something in python.py, then rename it to .cgi, then upload it to my server at :

```
/home/xxxxx/public_html/cgi-bin/python.cgi
```

Will this make my website automatically load and redirect there ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: We need information on which webserver you are using; does it even support python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use straight HTML to redirect to the website you want? I might not understand your question correctly, but for example

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">`

would redirect the user to http://example.com when loading your page.

Comment: can I put python script together with it ? Coz I need to extract some info from another web to put it to this link. Like this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829066/extract-text-from-website-source-code; can it be done easier by html and javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request.

When people load your web page, the page sends an AJAX request to some other site, and render  your page after getting the request result.

Comment: can we use that in middle of python code ? Coz I get the NEWSTRING using python

Comment: the AJAX request is sent in javascript via GET/POST method to a server, in your case, where your Python script runs. So write a handler for this AJAX request which returns data to the javascript.

Comment: are they coded in the same file (like inded.html) or what kind of link between them ? Can you give an example pls !

Comment: Have you successfully run your python script on some server?

Comment: It is the first time I think of using it on the server. But I think people must use it very often outthere

Comment: So first of all get your script running on the server. Take a look at this: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/365606/