# How to extract text from html page?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, text

For example the web page is the link:

> https://www.architecture.com/FindAnArchitect/FAAPractices.aspx?display=50

I must have the name of the firms and their address and website. I have tried the following to convert the html to text:

```
import nltk   
from urllib import urlopen

url = "https://www.architecture.com/FindAnArchitect/FAAPractices.aspx display=50"    
html = urlopen(url).read()    
raw = nltk.clean_html(html)  
print(raw)
```

But it returns the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'urlopen
```

Comment: You are using [Python 3 **`urllib`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html), which is different to [Python 2 **`urllib`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html)

Comment: Pretty sure you're going to be disappointed once you get it working: [**`clean_html`**](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/util.html#clean_html) is not implemented. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002076/python-nltk-clean-html-not-implemented).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Peter Wood has answered your problem ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566843/how-to-extract-text-from-html-page/33566923#comment54911928_33566843)).

```
import urllib.request

uf = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = uf.read()
```

But if you want to extract data (such as name of the firm, address and website) then you will need to fetch your HTML source and parse it using a HTML parser.

I'd suggest to use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/) for fetching the HTML source and [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the HTML generated and extract the text you require.

Here is a small snipet which will give you a head start.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.architecture.com/FindAnArchitect/FAAPractices.aspx?display=50"

html = requests.get(link).text

"""If you do not want to use requests then you can use the following code below 
   with urllib (the snippet above). It should not cause any issue."""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
res = soup.findAll("article", {"class": "listingItem"})
for r in res:
    print("Company Name: " + r.find('a').text)
    print("Address: " + r.find("div", {'class': 'address'}).text)
    print("Website: " + r.find_all("div", {'class': 'pageMeta-item'})[3].text)
```

Comment: nice, but what if i open a random site and i want to extract the important text like, i want scape the text of menu or the end of page i want just the topic direct.