# Can't get specific data from a HTML site in Python (3.6)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, parsing

Web page (about football and ratings) :

> http://www.fantagazzetta.com/voti-serie-a

What i tried:

> [How to extract text from html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566843/how-to-extract-text-from-html-page)

I tried using the code provided by the user JRodDynamite in his answer (and in the end just printing *res* and not doing the *for* thing). So i needed to edit just this part of the code (i guess):

```
res = soup.findAll("article", {"class": "listingItem"})
```

To print each table's content i thought the answer was:

```
res = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "table"})
```

But it's not printing anything. So I need your help: i would like to collect the data from that web page (player's name and rating) but i'm stuck on this point.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup, requests, etc. does not execute Javascript, so any data delivered or rendered via JS will not be available to you.

For JavaScript rendered pages you can try with [`dryscrape`](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape) like so:

```
import dryscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sess = dryscrape.Session()
sess.visit('http://www.fantagazzetta.com/voti-serie-a#')
s = BeautifulSoup(sess.body())
for a in s.find_all('table', {'class': 'table'}):
    print(a.text)
```

---

Dryscrape installation:

```
sudo pip install dryscrape
```

Comment: you could describe `dryscrape` for OP and others. Link to documentation could be nice too.