# Extract text from HTML faster than NLTK?

Tags: python, html, nltk, text-extraction

We use NLTK to extract text from HTML pages, but we want only most trivial text analysis, e.g. word count.

Is there a *faster* way to extract visible text from HTML using Python?

Understanding HTML (and ideally CSS) at some minimal level, like visible / invisible nodes, images' alt texts, etc, would be additionally great.

Comment: _How_ are you using the NLTK to process HTML pages? The nltk used to have a `clean_html()` function, but [dropped it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26002076)  back in 2014 and left the job to `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: @alexis: Hmm, a good question! After digging more through the sources, I see that `nltk` is only used to tokenize the text extracted by `html2text`! This changes the problem completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into the same problem at my previous workplace. You'll want to check out beautifulsoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.text
```

You'll find its documentation here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

You can ignore elements based on attributes. As to understanding external stylesheets im not too sure. However what you could do there and something that would not be too slow (depending on the page) is to look into rendering the page with something like phantomjs and then selecting the rendered text :)