# Exclude hidden tags while scraping using b4

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have a website that has plenty of hidden tags in the html.
I have pasted the source code below.
The challenge is that there are 2 types on hidden tags,

`1.` Ones with `style="display:none"`

`2.` They have list of styles mentioned under every `td` tag.

And it changes with every td tag.
for the example below it has the following styles,

```
hLcj{display:none}
.J9pE{display:inline}
.kUC-{display:none}
.Dzkb{display:inline}
.mXJU{display:none}
.DZqk{display:inline}
.rr9s{display:none}
.nGF_{display:inline}
```

So the elements with `class=hLcj, kUC, mXJU, rr9s,etc` are hidden elements

I want to extract the text of entire tr but exclude these hidden tags.
I have been scratching my head for hours and still no success.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks
I am using `bs4` and `python 2.7`

```
<td class="leftborder timestamp" rel="1416853322">
<td>
<span>
<style>
.hLcj{display:none}
.J9pE{display:inline}
.kUC-{display:none}
.Dzkb{display:inline}
.mXJU{display:none}
.DZqk{display:inline}
.rr9s{display:none}
.nGF_{display:inline}
</style>
<span class="rr9s">35</span>
<span></span>
<div style="display:none">121</div>
<span class="226">199</span>
.
<span class="rr9s">116</span>
<div style="display:none">116</div>
<span></span>
<span class="Dzkb">200</span>
<span style="display: inline">.</span>
<span style="display:none">86</span>
<span class="kUC-">86</span>
<span></span>
120
<span class="kUC-">134</span>
<div style="display:none">134</div>
<span class="mXJU">151</span>
<div style="display:none">151</div>
<span class="rr9s">154</span>
<span class="Dzkb">.</span>
<span class="119">36</span>
<span class="kUC-">157</span>
<div style="display:none">157</div>
<span class="rr9s">249</span>
<div style="display:none">249</div>
</span>
</td>
<td> 7808</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using selenium would make the task much easier since it knows what elements are hidden and which aren't.

But, anyway, here's a basic code that you would probably need to improve more. The idea here is to parse the `style` tag and get the list of classes to exclude, have a list of tags to exclude and check the `style` attribute of each child element in `tr`:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """ your html here """

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
tr = soup.tr

# get classes to exclude
classes_to_exclude = []
for line in tr.style.text.split():
    match = re.match(r'^\.(.*?)\{display:none\}', line)
    if match:
        classes_to_exclude.append(match.group(1))

tags_to_exclude = ['style', 'script']

texts = []
for item in tr.find_all(text=True):
    if item.parent.name in tags_to_exclude:
        continue

    class_ = item.parent.get('class')
    if class_ and class_[0] in classes_to_exclude:
        continue

    if item.parent.get('style') == 'display:none':
        continue

    texts.append(item)

print ''.join(texts.strip())
```

Prints:

```
199.200.120.36
```

Also see:

- [BeautifulSoup Grab Visible Webpage Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936466/beautifulsoup-grab-visible-webpage-text)