# Check that text is visible on a page across HTML elements

Tags: selenium

I want to check whether certain text (say "A unicorn") is *visible* on an HTML page using Selenium (Python if it matters).

However, for unrelated reasons the page has the following structure (simplified):

```
<div>
  <span style="display: none">A</span> <span style="display: none">unicorn</span>
</div>
```

The check used in [Lettuce Webdriver](https://github.com/koterpillar/aloe_webdriver) and [Aloe Webdriver](https://github.com/bbangert/lettuce_webdriver) is:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '//*[contains(normalize-space(.),"{content}")'.format(text))
```

and then checking the returned elements for `is_displayed`. However, this will find the outer `div` element and its text will contain the searched string even though the string is not actually visible to the user.

How can I check that some text is *visible* on the page, even if it spans multiple elements?

Respective bugs: [Aloe Webdriver bug](https://github.com/koterpillar/aloe_webdriver/issues/13), [Lettuce Webdriver bug](https://github.com/bbangert/lettuce_webdriver/issues/58).

Comment: You could use beautifulsoup perhaps... see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27115266/499581

Comment: This requires me to reimplement a CSS parser since the actual web page might use classes and not simply `display: none`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult scenario. For the specific example you have given, the following code should work. The code basically splits "A unicorn" into 2 words and finds the individual elements. After finding the individual span tags, the parents of each element are found and compared for equality. If the parent are equal, each individual element is for display property.

```
public class ComplicatedSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("url");

        // Look if "A unicorn" occurs within a single element
        WebElement element = getElement(driver, "A unicorn");
        if (element != null) {
            if (element.isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("Text is displayed");
            }
        }

        // Split "A unicorn" into 2 String and find the individual elements
        WebElement part1 = getElement(driver, "A");
        WebElement part2 = getElement(driver, "unicorn");

        if (part1 != null && part2 != null) {
            // find the parents of part1 and part2 and compare whether they are
            // equal
            if (findParent(driver, "A").equals(findParent(driver, "unicorn"))) {
                // if parents are equal, check if both elements are displayed
                if (part1.isDisplayed() && part2.isDisplayed()) {
                    System.out.println("Text is displayed");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Text is not displyed");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static WebElement getElement(WebDriver driver, String keyword) {
        try {
            return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[.='" + keyword + "']"));
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static WebElement findParent(WebDriver driver, String keyword) {
        try {
            return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[.='" + keyword + "']/.."));
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

For making this scenario generic a lot of effort and many conditions would have to be incorporated. Happy coding!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Something like this is what I have done to work around my immediate problem, but I don't think it can work in the generic case.