# How to replace extracted HTML tags in a text with a blank?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am extracting text from an html page without all tags (using Python and BeautifulSoup). However, tags are not replaced with a blank. So, for example, for "blah blahDIVTAGblah" I get the following text "blah blahblah". How can I insert a blank between the second and third blah? I am using the following code.

```
# kill all script and style elements
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract()
```

The code is from [BeautifulSoup Grab Visible Webpage Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936466/beautifulsoup-grab-visible-webpage-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace the tags with blank using [`.replace_with()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) :

```
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.replace_with(" ")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @har07. I think this is the way to go. In the end, I decided to replace the tags with a regular expression (e.g., `html = re.sub('<li>', ' LIST_BULLET ', html`) as this was better for my concrete problem.