# Python removing website html tags not working

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing

I am trying to remove the text inside the <>(html tags) and write the outcome to a new file. For example, one line of text could be:

```
< asdf> Text <here>more text< /asdf >
```

So the program would write to the output file: "Text more text", excluding those inside the html tags.

This is my attempt so far:

```
import urllib.request

data=urllib.request.urlopen("some website").read()

text1=data.decode("utf-8")

import re

def asd(text1):

    x=re.compile("<>")

    y=re.sub(x,"",text1)

    file1=open("textfileoutput.txt","w")

    file1.write(y)

    return y

asd(text1)
```

It doesn't seem to write the clean version, still has the tags. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your regular expression will only match "<>". I suggest a solution like [BeautifulSoup Grab Visible Webpage Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936466/beautifulsoup-grab-visible-webpage-text).

Comment: You are right, fixed it with replacing a line with this: x=re.compile(r"<[^>]+>") Program works now. Thank you.

Comment: What if the tag contains a > somewhere in it? As alecxe pointed out, trying to parse HTML with regular expressions is usually not the best.

Answer (score 2):

```
x=re.compile("<>")
```

I am not sure why do you think this expression is going to match `< asdf>` or `< /asdf >`.

In any case, approaching HTML with regular expressions [can rarely be justified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/771848). *Use a more appropriate tool for the task - an HTML parser*.

Example using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and it's [`unwrap()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap):

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: html = "<asdf>Text more text</asdf>"

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

In [4]: soup.asdf.unwrap()
Out[4]: <asdf></asdf>

In [5]: print(soup)
Text more text
```

Comment: For some others who cares about performance, `BeautifulSoup` is really slow even uses `lxml` as parser. If your html text is affirmatively well-formatted and you trust your regex expression, there is no problem to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `re.compile("<>")` with `re.compile(r"<[^<>]*>")` is enough

Comment: What if the tag contains a > somewhere in it?