# Is any posibility to extract certain html tags from a string using python

Tags: python, html

For example, I have a big chunk of text that has HTML tags in there and I want to have a function that is removing HTML tags from my code.
But I want to delete just the tags not text.
The problem is more complicated than it seems because if you have some ol or ul tags and I want to delete ol first I don't want the text to be delete and 
the li tag to be deleted but just for ol tag, not for ul.

I have tried to use BeautifulSoup and some NLP  tehnics but with no success

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

html_know='''<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGTVf63Vm3XgOncMVSOy0-jSxdMT8KVJIc8WiWaevuWiPGe0Pm" class="image_master" alt="" style="width: 248px; height: 164px; vertical-align: middle;">

<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGTVf63Vm3XgOncMVSOy0-jSxdMT8KVJIc8WiWaevuWiPGe0Pm" style="width: 250px; height: 166px;">

<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGTVf63Vm3XgOncMVSOy0-jSxdMT8KVJIc8WiWaevuWiPGe0Pm" style="width: 249px; height: 165px;">



<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGTVf63Vm3XgOncMVSOy0-jSxdMT8KVJIc8WiWaevuWiPGe0Pm" style="width: 249px; height: 165px;">




<p></p>
<p><strong><span style="font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif; font-size: 36px;">HTML</span></strong></p> <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);"><p></p>HTML stands for Hyper Text Markup Language, which is the most widely used language on Web to develop web pages. HTML was created by Berners-Lee in late 1991 but "HTML 2.0" was the first standard HTML specification which was published in 1995. HTML 4.01 was a major version of HTML and it was published in late 1999.</span>Though
HTML 4.01 version is widely used but currently we are having HTML-5 version which is an extension to HTML 4.01, and this version was published in 2012. Audience This tutorial is designed for the aspiring Web Designers and Developers with a need to understand
the HTML in enough detail along with its simple overview, and practical examples. This tutorial will give you enough ingredients to start with HTML from where you can take yourself at higher level of expertise.
<p></p>
<p>



</p>
<p></p>HTML stands for Hypertext Markup Language, and it is the most widely used language to write Web Pages. Hypertext refers to the way in which Web pages (HTML documents) are linked together. Thus, the link available on a webpage is called Hypertext.
As its name suggests, HTML is a Markup Language which means you use HTML to simply "mark-up" a text document with tags that tell a Web browser how to structure it to display. Originally, HTML was developed with the intent of defining the structure of
documents like headings, paragraphs, lists, and so forth to facilitate the sharing of scientific information between researchers. Now, HTML is being widely used to format web pages with the help of different tags available in HTML language. Basic HTML
Document In its simplest form, following is an example of an HTML document
<p></p>
<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" style="width: 119px; height: 119px;"></p>

<table style="width:100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Firstname</th>
            <th style="border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Lastname</th>
            <th style="border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Jill</td>
            <td style="border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Smith</td>
            <td style="border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Eve</td>
            <td style="border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Jackson</td>
            <td style="border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">94</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>HTML Tags As told earlier, HTML is a markup language and makes use of various tags to format the content. These tags are enclosed within angle braces Except few tags, most of the tags have their corresponding closing tags. For example, has its closing
tag and tag has its closing tag tag etc. Above example of HTML document uses the following tags ? Sr.No Tag &amp; Description 1 This tag defines the document type and HTML version. 2 This tag encloses the complete HTML document and mainly comprises of
document header which is represented by ... and document body which is represented by ... tags. 3 This tag represents the document's header which can keep other HTML tags like html,head,body,title,...etc
<ol>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ol>
<ul>
    <li>sdfsdf</li>
    <li>s</li>
    <li>dfsd</li>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>sd</li>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>sd</li>
</ul>
<p></p>
<p><iframe width="1019px" height="311px" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/uCg2BoKiuOM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html_know, 'html.parser')
tags=soup.find_all('table')

print(tags[0].text)


print(html_know[3])
```

The idea behind this is that sometimes I want to delete some tags and other times to delete other tags.

PLease if you can give me some idea to this without to hard code everything

Comment: This might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936466/beautifulsoup-grab-visible-webpage-text

Comment: I looked but is not what i really want

Comment: Then, it might be easier that you give us a small example of the trickiest part with the expected result.