# beautifulsoup-grab-visible-webpage-text without a file ending in .html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I liked the answers I get on this page: [BeautifulSoup Grab Visible Webpage Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936466/beautifulsoup-grab-visible-webpage-text)

But my page doesn't end in .html, it's: https://biogmagscience.net

There must be a simple solution to this.

Cheers

Comment: DNS lookup is failing on that website. Did you mean,https://biomagscience.net/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your URL, should be https://biomagscience.net/ 
This script will print printable text using `get_text()` method:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://biomagscience.net/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

for tag in soup.select('style, script, [style*="display:none"]'):
    tag.extract()

print(soup.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
```

Prints:

```
Best Magnets For Healing | Biomagnetic Therapy Products
The Future of Health & Well-Being —Today!
Advanced Therapy for Vitality, Nerve Regeneration & Pain Relief of Acute/Chronic Injuries & Illness
Acute Injuries
•
Alzheimer’s
•
Arthritis
•
Back Pain
•
Chronic Illness
•
EMF
•
Joint Pain
•
Muscle Pain
Magnet Therapy Articles
•
Products
BiomagScience

...and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

https://biogmagscience.net is the URL, not the file name. Go to your website, download the source code, it will be in html.