# Raw text extraction from multiple URLs

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

[Given a list of URLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMoyi.png) pointing to different News Websites, I would like to scrape enough raw text from those articles to generate keywords with nltk (NLP).
But every News website is structured and parsed differently, is there a way to get only the raw text?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [BeautifulSoup Grab Visible Webpage Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936466/beautifulsoup-grab-visible-webpage-text/1983219#1983219).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup Grab Visible Webpage Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936466/beautifulsoup-grab-visible-webpage-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it. For example, you can simply use `requests` like below.

```
import requests
url = "https://wasi0013.com/"
content = requests.get(url).content
```

As, you are trying to scrape multiple news websites. You might have to parse websites that use Javascript to render. Contents that are rendered with JS can't be fetched using `requests`. For those, You can use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) with [chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) or, [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) to scrape raw texts.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {
    'profile.managed_default_content_settings.images': 2,
}
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
url = "https://wasi0013.com"
driver.get(url)
raw_text = driver.page_source
```

note that, in the above code I've disabled images as we only need texts. This will load the pages slightly faster. Check out the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) for more details.