# How to extract texture strings between two tags with different level with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, beautifulsoup, extract

I want to extract the all contents between two tags with different level.
After google, i can't find the effective solutions for my need.

I expect you have solultions with Python.

so please see the html code below:

```
<span id='info'> 
    <span> 
        <span class='cl'>text1</span>
        <a href="">text2 is Chinese string.</a>
        text3
    </span>
    <br 1>
    <span class='cl'> text4</span> text5
     <br 2>
    <span class='cl'> 
        <span>text7</span>
        <a href="">text8</a>
        text9
    </span>
    <br 3>
    <span class='cl'> text10</span> text11
     <br 4>
    <span class='cl'> text12</span> text13
     <br 5>
</span>
```

And, before first `<br 1>` tag, the html in some pages is like below:

```
# one situation below:

<span id='info'> 
    <span> 
        <span class='cl'>text1</span>
        <a href="">text2 is Chinese string.</a>
        <a href="">text2 is Chinese string.</a>
        text3
    </span>
    <br 1>
    <span class='cl'> text4</span> text5
     ......other html....
</span>

# two situation below:

<span id='info'> 
        <span class='cl'>text1</span>
        <a href="">text2 is Chinese string.</a>
        text3
    <br 1>
    <span class='cl'> text4</span> text5
     ......other html....
</span>
```

I want to extract contents:

```
text1 text2 text3 .... text13
```

I tried Xpath and bs4 for very very more methods, but there were no ok for my need.
Could you tell me the right way to use Xpath or bs4 or other mehods to get the expected output above?
Thank you in advance!

Xpath I tried:

```
str = response.xpath("//span[@id='info']/descendant::span[contains(text(),'text1')]/following::br[1]/preceding-sibling::node()")
str = str.xpath('string(.)').extract()
print(str)
```

then i got(like below):

```
[' \n \n text1 \n \n tex2  \n  tex3  \n    \n]
```

Above is the contents before first `<br >` tag. Because the html tags is not stable in different pages eventhough they are from same website, in the area of `<span id='info'>`. So i have to extract the contents between two neighbouring `<br >` tags separately.

And soup didn't work, i did not study it.

For my want, just the `<br>` tags have the stable postions and status. So i want use `<br>` tags to position the informations ( one br, one infomation ).

So, how can i do?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Hanoso! Can you share the bs4 and/or Xpath code you've tried so far? Maybe someone can identify the issue.

Comment: Yes. see below.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see your code... can you edit your question to add it?

Comment: Sorry for that. I just edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, [don't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/684776).

But if all the HTML you want to parse looks very similar to your example, then... do what works!

```
(?<=>)(?:\s*)[^(<|\s).]+(?=\s*<)
```

That will capture the text and leading whitespace. Then you can `.trim()` to the content you want.

[See it in action on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OUMjmR/2).

Comment: Thanks!  But that doesn't meet my want. It' more complex.

Comment: @HanosoCao you bet! How does it fail? Maybe it can be tweaked to meet your needs.

Comment: Yes. It work, but just got numbers. The string is all Chinese.

Comment: @HanosoCao just updated to make it better handle the Chinese characters.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks a lot! It's very useful for me.

Comment: @HanosoCao if either/both of these answers are helpful, please give them an "upvote" - if one solves your problem, hit the checkmark to mark it as the solution. It gives me credit for the effort and helps others find solutions they need!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try for a BeautifulSoup solution... It's almost completely stolen from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1983219/684776

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment
import urllib.request

def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']:
        return False
    if isinstance(element, Comment):
        return False
    return True


def text_from_html(body):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)  
    return list(filter(lambda x: x != '', [t.strip() for t in visible_texts]))

html = """
<span id='info'> 
    <span class='cl'> 
        <span>text1</span>
        <a href="">text2</a>
        text3
    </span>
    <br 1>
    <span class='cl'> text4</span> text5
     <br 2>
    <span class='cl'> 
        <span>text7</span>
        <a href="">text8</a>
        text9
    </span>
    <br 3>
    <span class='cl'> text10</span> text11
     <br 4>
    <span class='cl'> text12</span> text13
     <br 5>
</span>
"""

print(text_from_html(html))
```

Test in on Repl.it: https://repl.it/@mac9416/SO-57890610

Comment: Thank you! It's worked. I know this method. But the html source is not stable like my  example, there are difference in different pages. So it's good in some pages, but bad in another specific pages.   https://repl.it/@Hanoso/SurefootedBestOutcome

Comment: @HanosoCao you bet! Whichever solution you pursue, you might get the best help by posting separate questions for the specific problems with the solution.

Comment: You are right. I will try more solutions. And think about separating my questions.

Comment: @HanosoCao Good luck!