# How to scan a particular web address, and then print the text

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am attempting to scan a website, and then print all of the text (I have no need for taking text from only certain tags). Here is my code so far:

```
username = input('Enter the username, then press Enter ')
url = 'https://apiktracer.herokuapp.com/user/'+username
```

I do not know what I need to do next. Would I need to import any libraries?

Comment: this is probably pretty similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1983219/10077641

you would use the beautiful soup library to do this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup Grab Visible Webpage Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936466/beautifulsoup-grab-visible-webpage-text)

Comment: How would I do that, but it prints all the text from the page, no matter what?