# Website server redirects me but get 200 as status code

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm learning web scraping with python, and as a way to do an all-in-one exercise I'm trying to make a game catalog by utilizing Beautiful Soup and requests modules as my main tools. Though, the problem lies while handling sentences related to requests module.

**DESCRIPTION:**

The exercise is about getting all genres tags used for classifying games starting with A letter in the first page. Each page shows around or exactly 30 games, so if one wants to access  a specific page independently of a letter, has to access to an url in this form.

1. https://vandal.elespanol.com/juegos/13/pc/letra/a/inicio/1
2. https://vandal.elespanol.com/juegos/13/pc/letra/a/inicio/2
3. https://vandal.elespanol.com/juegos/13/pc/letra/a/inicio/3

And so on...
As a matter of fact, each alphabet letter main page has the form:
URL: https://vandal.elespanol.com/juegos/13/pc/letra/ *which is equivalent to* https://vandal.elespanol.com/juegos/13/pc/letra/a/inicio/.

Making my way to scrape genres from some pages is not big deal but what if i want to scrape them all of a letter, **how do i know when I'm done scraping genres from all games of a letter**?

When you request the url https://vandal.elespanol.com/juegos/13/pc/letra/a/inicio/200 for example, you get redirected to a corresponding letter main page, which means the first 30 games, since in the end it doesn't have more games to return.
So while bearing that in mind.. i was thinking about *verifying the status_code* got from requests.get() response, but get a 200 as status code whereas when analizing packages received with Chrome Tools i got 301 as status code. In the end of the program i save to a file the scraped genres.

**Here's the picture.**
[image]

**And here's the code**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import string
import requests
from string import ascii_lowercase



def write_genres_to_file(site_genres): 
    with open('/home/l0new0lf/Desktop/generos.txt', 'w') as file_:
        print(f'File "{file_.name}" OPENED to write {len(site_genres)} GENRES')
        counter = 1
        site_genres_length = len(site_genres)
        for num in range(site_genres_length):
            print('inside File Loop')
            if counter != 2:
                if counter == 3:
                    file_.write(f'{site_genres[num]}' + '\n')
                    print('wrote something')
                    counter = 0
                    
                else: file_.write(f'{site_genres[num]}')
                
            else: file_.write(f'{site_genres[num]:^{len(site_genres[num])+8}}')
            print(f'Wrote genre "{site_genres[num]}" SUCCESSFULLY!')
            counter +=1 

def get_tags():

    #TITLE_TAG_SELECTOR = 'tr:first-child td.ta14b.t11 div a strong'
    #IMG_TAG_SELECTOR = 'tr:last-child td:first-child a img'
    #DESCRIPTION_TAG_SELECTOR = 'tr:last-child td:last-child p'
    GENRES_TAG_SELECTOR = 'tr:last-child td:last-child div.mt05 p'
    GAME_SEARCH_RESULTS_TABLE_SELECTOR = 'table.mt1.tablestriped4.froboto_real.blanca'

    GAME_TABLES_CLASS = 'table transparente tablasinbordes'

    site_genres = []

    for i in ['a']:
        counter = 1

        while True:
            rq = requests.get(f'https://vandal.elespanol.com/juegos/13/pc/letra/{i}/inicio/{counter}')
            
            
            if rq: 
                print('Request GET: from ' + f'https://vandal.elespanol.com/juegos/13/pc/letra/{i}/inicio/{counter}' + ' Got Workable Code !')
                
            
            if rq.status_code == 301 or rq.status_code == 302 or rq.status_code == 303 or rq.status_code == 304:
                print(f'No more games in letter {i}\n**REDIRECTING TO **')
                break

            counter +=1
                            
            soup = BeautifulSoup(rq.content, 'lxml')
            main_table = soup.select_one(GAME_SEARCH_RESULTS_TABLE_SELECTOR)
            #print('This is the MAIN TABLE:\n' + str(main_table))
            game_tables = main_table.find_all('table', {'class': GAME_TABLES_CLASS})
            #print('These are the GAME TABLES:\n' + str(game_tables))
            for game in game_tables:

                genres_str = str(game.select_one(GENRES_TAG_SELECTOR).contents[1]).strip().split(' / ')
                for genre in genres_str:
                    if not genre in site_genres:
                        site_genres.append(genre)
            
            
    write_genres_to_file(site_genres)
    
            
get_tags()
```

So, *roughly*, **my question is**: **How do could i know when i'm done scraping all games starting with a certain letter in order to start scraping the games from the next one?**.

NOTE: I only could think of comparing every time in the loop if returned html structure is the same compared with first page of a letter or maybe evaluating if I'm receiving repeated games. But i think this shouldn't the way i go about.

Any help is truly welcomed, and I'm very sorry for the very looong problem description, but thought that it was necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply would not just rely on a status code. You might get a non `200` status even for pages that are there. For example if you exceed a certain amount described in their `robots.txt`, or if your network has a delay or error.

So, to reply to your question: "How do I ensure that I scraped all pages corresponding to a certain letter?". To ensure it you may save all the "visible text" as in this reply [BeautifulSoup Grab Visible Webpage Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936466/beautifulsoup-grab-visible-webpage-text?noredirect=1&lq=1) and hash its content. When you hit the same hash, then you know that you already crawled/scraped that page. Therefore you can then incrementally go on the next letter.

As an example of hash snippet, I would use the following:

```
def from_text_to_hash(url: str) -> str:
    """ Getting visible-text and hashing it"""
    url_downloaded = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url_downloaded, "lxml")
    visible_text = soup.title.text + "\t" + soup.body.text
    current_hash = str(hash(visible_text))
    return current_hash
```

And you keep track in a set of the variable `current_hash`

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, it really solves the problem at hand, but each letter has around 200 pages, each one with a lot of text to save. Saving all this into memory  would be very inefficient AFAIK in terms of memory.

Comment: You don't have to save the text, you extract the visible text, hash it and store in a "set" data structure its hash. As you say, if each letter has around 200 pages, then you will save 200 hash. A hash is way shorter. Hope this explains :)