# Detect commentaries from webpage while web scrapping

Tags: python, web-scraping, text, text-classification

I am trying to web scrapping sites with reviews and i get all site blocks
I need to extract user's comments from scrapped web-page, how can i do it?
I have two probably directions how to do this:

1. Somehow detect which site block contains commentaries and extract from those blocks but some sites have very strange html syntax and it hard to detect from tags - now i am trying something like recommend in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936466/beautifulsoup-grab-visible-webpage-text) but it work not good enought.
2. Some text classification of text block on site but i cant fiud any models/apis to deal with this classification problem

Comment: are there a lot of websites and you need a unique thing to scrape them all at once?

Comment: @DmitriyNeledva I thought of parsing them one by one and it is possible decision but i have about 30-40 most common sites and it looks too long

Comment: 'most common' you mean they are similar in html structure? show us their html

Comment: most common with absolutley different html structure

Comment: most common - i mean for for most requests to my app i need info from 10-20 sites

Comment: If they are absolutely different you need to write scraper for each separately

Comment: If I can't find a better way, I'll do it like this ty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249258/discussion-between-dmitriy-neledva-and-vasily).